# Eclipse+Pydev+pylab: STACK: Stack after current is in use

Tags: eclipse, plot, stack, pydev

when I try to plot a figure I get an error message: "STACK: Stack after current is in use".
I used a code like this:

```
import numpy as np  
from pylab import      
n = 256  
X = np.linspace(-np.pi,np.pi,n,endpoint=True)  
Y = np.sin(2*X)  

plot (X, Y+1, color='blue', alpha=1.00)  
plot (X, Y-1, color='blue', alpha=1.00)
show()
```

Does someone know how to solve this problem?

Best,
Marius

PS.: I'm using Mac OS ML, Python 2.7, Pydev+Eclipse

Comment: I was able to save an image using the command line: plt.savefig('myfilename.png'). Apparently I can save an image, but not show it while running eclipse?!

Comment: does someone has an idea? i've the same problem trying to plot something using the terminal

Answer (score 1):

I'm not pretty sure that I have understand the error you mentioned, however in the code you have quoted, you are missing an "`*`" after `from pylab import`
That is:

```
import numpy as np  
from pylab import *      
n = 256  
X = np.linspace(-np.pi,np.pi,n,endpoint=True)  
Y = np.sin(2*X)  

plot (X, Y+1, color='blue', alpha=1.00)  
plot (X, Y-1, color='blue', alpha=1.00)
show()
```

The following code produced a figure with 2 sinus waves using eclipse juno+pydev+pylab

Answer (score 0):

I spent a day handling this problem and finally found it is the problem of your python version. I installed the 32-bit python 2.7 and also met error message: "STACK: Stack after current is in use".

On the github page of matplotlib(https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/downloads), the description of matplotlib-1.2.0-py2.7-python.org-macosx10.6.dmg is "Binary installer for python.org's 64-bit python 2.7 and MacOS X 10.6 or later".

After I changed to matplotlib-1.2.0-py2.7-python.org-macosx10.3.dmg which matches 32-bit python, the problem was solved.